# Why my exported UV map is different in size?

Tags: mesh, texturing, uv, uv-image-editor, external-applications

I did unwrap my mesh which consists of several parts. I did an export using EPS file format, then I applied several images to all the faces in Adobe Illustrator.

When I try to import the texture back into Blender the map is slightly off or just out of scale:

[image]

**Q:** Why the export is different in size? What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Hello :). Your canvas in Illustrator isn't perfectly square. That's why the UV doesn't perfectly align. You exported the UV from Blender as curves, right?

Comment: Hi Jachym yes i exported as an eps and opened in illustrator did not move and exportes as a jpeg?

Comment: Hi Jachym, i exported UV as an eps. Opened it in illustrator. Did not alter in any way exported as jpeg and applied. So not really sure it could be that?

Comment: Hey, it must be a bug  :). If you export it as SVG, it works just fine. But EPS is buggy.

Comment: Ok let me try that :)

Comment: Sir you are 100% correct

Comment: If you think that's a bug consider to file a bug report @JachymMichal

Comment: @brockmann Not sure yet, might be because EPS doesn't support canvas :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Don't use EPS to transfer UV maps - it only exports the occupied area.
Use SVG instead, it exports the whole UV canvas.

[image]

Comment: Thank you yes this has solved the problem. Phew every step along the way is a new school day but its good fun.

Comment: I feel the same way sometimes :). Good luck with your project, feel free to ask more questions if you get stuck anywhere.

Comment: @XxSTxRMxNxX consider to mark answer as accepted, it keeps site organised https://blender.stackexchange.com/tour Thank you

Comment: Not sure how to mark as accepted :(

Comment: Ha big green arrow. Done